Expandable row does not collapse/expand and order incorrect all the sub item using JavaScript
I am having an issue with my JavaScript code. I was able to successfully implement the collapse and expand functionality for individual sub-items, but when I try to use the header as a master control to collapse and expand all sub-items at once, it doesn't work. Additionally, when I click the header, it shows extra sub-items that are not related to the table.
Problem 1 : I found that the tbody selector is not working.
const subSections = targetSection.querySelectorAll('tbody');
Problem 2 : When clicking the second time,extra sub-items appear.The sub-item order is also incorrect.
targetSection.style.display = 'table-row-group';
Before :image before clicked.
After : Image after clicked. 
Expected Result:
I want the 2.0 Variation Order to act as the master control for all child items, such as sub-items like V0-002, allowing them to collapse and expand.
htmlDesign
html 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Variation Orders</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/css/file.css"> <!-- Link to your CSS file -->
    <style>
        /* Basic styling for clarity */
        .table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
        .table th, .table td { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; }
        .bg-light { background-color: #f8f9fa; }
        .bg-white { background-color: #ffffff; }
        .fw-bold { font-weight: bold; }
        .text-end { text-align: right; }
        .text-click { cursor: pointer; }
        .text-danger { color: red; }
        .expandable-header { cursor: pointer; }
        .toggle-icon, .toggle-all-icon { cursor: pointer; }
        .arrow { display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; transform: rotate(0deg); transition: transform 0.3s ease; }
        .down { transform: rotate(90deg); }
        .up { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-light expandable-header" data-target="#variationOrdersSection">
                <td colspan="10" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; cursor: pointer;">
                    <span class="toggle-all-icon"><i class="arrow down"></i></span> 2.0 Variation Order
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="variationOrdersSection" style="display:none;">
            <!-- Example rendering for variation orders -->
            <tr class="bg-white fw-bold" 
                data-total-claim="5000" 
                data-to-date-percent="75"
                data-to-date="3750" 
                data-current-percent="25" 
                data-current="1250"
                data-previous-percent="50" 
                data-previous="2500"
                data-name="VO-001" 
                data-variation-id="1"
                data-target="#variation-1">

                <td>
                    <span class="toggle-icon" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; cursor: pointer;" 
                          data-target="#variation-1">
                        <i class="arrow down"></i>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-capitalize ps-3">VO-001</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-end">$5,000.00</td>
                <td class="text-end">75%</td>
                <td class="text-end">$3,750.00</td>
                <td class="text-end">50%</td>
                <td class="text-end">$2,500.00</td>
                <td class="text-end">25%</td>
                <td class="text-end">$1,250.00</td>
            </tr>

            <tbody id="variation-1" style="display:none;">
                <!-- Example parent section for the variation -->
                <tr class="client-progress-claim-sub-section fw-bold" 
                    parent-section-id="101"
                    sub-section-name="Electrical" 
                    variation-order-id="1">

                    <td></td>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td><span>Electrical</span></td>
                    <td class="text-end sub-section-amount">$2,000.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">40%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$800.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">30%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$600.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">10%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$200.00</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Sub-sections under the parent section -->
                <tr class="client-progress-claim-sub-section" 
                    parent-section-id="101" 
                    sub-section-id="201"
                    sub-section-name="Wiring" 
                    variation-order-id="1">

                    <td></td>
                    <td>A.1</td>
                    <td><a href="/ProgressClaim/item/1/variationorder/1/lineitems/101/201">Wiring</a></td>
                    <td class="text-end sub-section-amount">$1,000.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">50%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$500.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">30%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$300.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end">20%</td>
                    <td class="text-end">$200.00</td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Subtotal for the parent section -->
                <tr class="client-progress-claim-section-sub-total bg-light" parent-section-id="101">
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right"><b>Section A - Sub-total</b></td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">$2,000.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">40%</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">$800.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">30%</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">$600.00</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">10%</td>
                    <td class="text-end fw-bold">$200.00</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // Handle the main Variation Order header toggle
            const mainToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.expandable-header');

            mainToggles.forEach(function (toggle) {
                toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    // Get the target tbody to toggle
                    const targetId = toggle.getAttribute('data-target');
                    const targetSection = document.querySelector(targetId);

                    // If the section doesn't exist, do nothing
                    if (!targetSection) return;

                    // Find the arrow inside the toggle
                    const arrowIcon = toggle.querySelector('.arrow');

                    // Check if the target section is currently visible or not
                    const isHidden = targetSection.style.display === 'none' || targetSection.style.display === '';

                    // Toggle the main section visibility
                    if (isHidden) {
                        targetSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show the main section
                        arrowIcon.classList.remove('down');
                        arrowIcon.classList.add('up');

                        // Expand all sub-items (assumes sub-items are tbody elements within targetSection)
                        const subSections = targetSection.querySelectorAll('tbody');
                        console.log("subSections:", subSections);
                        subSections.forEach(function (subSection) {
                            subSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show all sub-items
                        });

                        // Change all sub-item arrows to 'up'
                        const subArrows = targetSection.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon .arrow');
                        subArrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                            arrow.classList.remove('down');
                            arrow.classList.add('up');
                        });
                    } else {
                        targetSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the main section
                        arrowIcon.classList.remove('up');
                        arrowIcon.classList.add('down');

                        // Collapse all sub-items
                        const subSections = targetSection.querySelectorAll('tbody');
                        subSections.forEach(function (subSection) {
                            subSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide all sub-items
                        });

                        // Change all sub-item arrows to 'down'
                        const subArrows = targetSection.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon .arrow');
                        subArrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                            arrow.classList.remove('up');
                            arrow.classList.add('down');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            // Handle sub-item toggles (for each sub-item in the variation orders)
            const subItemToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon');

            subItemToggles.forEach(function (icon) {
                icon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    // Prevent the event from affecting the main header toggle
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    // Get the target tbody for the sub-items
                    const targetId = icon.getAttribute('data-target');
                    const targetSection = document.querySelector(targetId);

                    // If the section doesn't exist, do nothing
                    if (!targetSection) return;

                    // Find the arrow inside the icon
                    const arrowIcon = icon.querySelector('.arrow');

                    // Check if the target section is currently visible or not
                    const isHidden = targetSection.style.display === 'none' || targetSection.style.display === '';

                    // Use 'table-row-group' to show the sub-items properly
                    if (isHidden) {
                        targetSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show the sub-items
                        arrowIcon.classList.remove('down');
                        arrowIcon.classList.add('up');
                    } else {
                        targetSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the sub-items
                        arrowIcon.classList.remove('up');
                        arrowIcon.classList.add('down');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

JavaScript

<script> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { 
// Handle the main Variation Order header toggle 
const mainToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.expandable-header');
mainToggles.forEach(function (toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Get the target tbody to toggle
        const targetId = toggle.getAttribute('data-target');
        const targetSection = document.querySelector(targetId);

        // If the section doesn't exist, do nothing
        if (!targetSection) return;

        // Find the arrow inside the toggle
        const arrowIcon = toggle.querySelector('.arrow');

        // Check if the target section is currently visible or not
const isHidden = targetSection.style.display === 'none' || targetSection.style.display === '';

        // Toggle the main section visibility
        if (isHidden) {
            targetSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show the main section
            arrowIcon.classList.remove('down');
            arrowIcon.classList.add('up');

           // Expand all sub-items (assumes sub-items are tbody elements within targetSection)
            const subSections = targetSection.querySelectorAll('tbody');
                console.log("subSections:", subSections);
            subSections.forEach(function (subSection) {
                subSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show all sub-items
            });

            // Change all sub-item arrows to 'up'
            const subArrows = targetSection.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon .arrow');
            subArrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                arrow.classList.remove('down');
                arrow.classList.add('up');
            });
        } else {
            targetSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the main section
            arrowIcon.classList.remove('up');
            arrowIcon.classList.add('down');

            // Collapse all sub-items
            const subSections = targetSection.querySelectorAll('tbody');
            subSections.forEach(function (subSection) {
                subSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide all sub-items
            });

            // Change all sub-item arrows to 'down'
            const subArrows = targetSection.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon .arrow');
            subArrows.forEach(function (arrow) {
                arrow.classList.remove('up');
                arrow.classList.add('down');
            });
        }
    });
});

// Handle sub-item toggles (for each sub-item in the variation orders)
const subItemToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-icon');

subItemToggles.forEach(function (icon) {
    icon.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // Prevent the event from affecting the main header toggle
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Get the target tbody for the sub-items
        const targetId = icon.getAttribute('data-target');
        const targetSection = document.querySelector(targetId);

        // If the section doesn't exist, do nothing
        if (!targetSection) return;

        // Find the arrow inside the icon
        const arrowIcon = icon.querySelector('.arrow');

        // Check if the target section is currently visible or not
const isHidden = targetSection.style.display === 'none' || targetSection.style.display === '';

        // Use 'table-row-group' to show the sub-items properly
        if (isHidden) {
            targetSection.style.display = 'table-row-group'; // Show the sub-items
            arrowIcon.classList.remove('down');
            arrowIcon.classList.add('up');
        } else {
            targetSection.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the sub-items
            arrowIcon.classList.remove('up');
            arrowIcon.classList.add('down');
        }
    });
});
});

</script>


Does the JavaScript posted differ in some way from the JavaScript code that's already included in the HTML posted?  If so, what is that difference and which one are you asking about?  If not, why post it twice?  Please clarify and reduce the code to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, particularly as a runnable code snippet.

Hmm, I suppose a little more context is needed. What exactly do you want the program to do?
